# DNN Platform Community edition licensing

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm going to use DNN Platform (v7.x) website as wiki portal for web application I'm working on.

Question: what licensing rules are applied to it? During installation I wasn't asked to accept any agreement, and at http://dnnsoftware.com site is only info about their paid CMS Evoq (based on DNN). I understand that it is commnunity edition and it's free, but is it free for commercial use and there is no restrictions about that?

Please, provide me some official resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNN platform is an MIT licensed application, meaning you can pretty much do anything you want with it, even sell it to someone else for $1million dollars.

You can use it for a free website, you can use it for a paid website, you can use it to build a killer application and then sell that for billions of dollars.

edit: link to license -> https://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/license